# AngularJS model biding and validation crash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which is basically a custom input field

JS (InputFieldDirective.js):

```
function InputFieldDirective() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/Views/Directives/InputField.html',
        scope: {
            type: '@inputType',
            pattern: '@inputPattern',
            id: '@inputId',
            class: '@inputClass',
            mandatory: '@inputMandatory',
            autocomplete: '@inputAutocomplete',
            bindedModel: '=inputModel',
            placeholder: '@inputPlaceholder',
            icon: '@inputIcon',
            errorMessage: '@errorMessage'
        }
    }

    return directive;
};
```

HTML (InputField.html):

```
<div class="input-field-wrapper">
<i class="placeholder-icon {{ icon }}" ng-if="icon !== ''"></i>
<input type="{{ type }}" pattern="{{ pattern }}" id="{{ id }}" name="{{ id }}" class="{{ class }}" ng-required="mandatory == 'yes'" autocomplete="{{ autocomplete }}" ng-model="bindedModel" ng-class="{'empty': !bindedModel}">
<label class="placeholder-label">{{ placeholder }}</label>
<span class="focus-animation"></span>
```

So when I try to insert this in a random template file like this:

```
<input-field input-type="text" input-pattern="" input-id="loginEmail" input-class="form-control" input-required="true" input-autocomplete="off" input-model="login.loginData.username" input-placeholder="Email" input-icon="em-email" error-message="Invalid email address!"></input-field>
```

then it works like a charm. Connects the data model (which is handled and used in the template's controller) to the field. E.g: if I log the model 'loginData' (which contains the 'username' and the 'password' model) I get the correct result when I type something in the inputs. E.g:

```
Input values:       username: myUsername
                    password: myPassword
loginData model:    {username: 'myUsername', password: 'myPassword'}
```

BUT if I change the input-type to 'email' or 'url' (tested with some other values worked fine with 'text', 'password' 'date', 'search' etc.) then I start to type something in the input the loginData's 'username' variable magically disappears. E.g:

```
Input values:       username: myUsername
                    password: myPassword
loginData model:    {password: 'myPassword'}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is something wrong connecting the model to the directive's element? But if it is, why it occurs only at input type 'email' and 'url' (maybe with some others I haven't tested) and works fine with others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine with your code. The input types 'email' and 'url' only have a simple check if the content is valid. If it is not the model is still empty. Try to type a valid email-address or url. It should work.

Here is my test for it:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('inputfield', InputFieldDirective);

function InputFieldDirective() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><input type="{{ type }}" pattern="{{ pattern }}" id="{{ id }}" name="{{ id }}" autocomplete="{{ autocomplete }}" ng-model="bindedModel" ><label>{{ placeholder }}</label><span class="focus-animation"></span></div>',
        scope: {
            type: '@inputType',
            pattern: '@inputPattern',
            id: '@inputId',
            class: '@inputClass',
            mandatory: '@inputMandatory',
            autocomplete: '@inputAutocomplete',
            bindedModel: '=inputModel',
            placeholder: '@inputPlaceholder',
            icon: '@inputIcon',
            errorMessage: '@errorMessage'
        }
    }

    return directive;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <inputfield input-type="url" input-pattern="" input-id="loginEmail" input-class="form-control" input-required="true" input-autocomplete="off" input-model="login.loginData.url" input-placeholder="URL" input-icon="em-email" error-message="Invalid email address!"></inputfield>{{login.loginData.url}}
  <inputfield input-type="email" input-pattern="" input-id="loginEmail" input-class="form-control" input-required="true" input-autocomplete="off" input-model="login.loginData.email" input-placeholder="Email" input-icon="em-email" error-message="Invalid email address!"></inputfield>{{login.loginData.email}}
</div>
```